# How do I get the current iframe location from within the iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I've seen solutions like

```
top.document.getElementById('iframe_a').src
```

But the problem is, that I don't know the Iframes ID. My Application is running as a Gmail-Gadget and therefore I don't know which ID Google will generate.

So how can I get the URL of my gadget?

Using JQuery will also be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your script is executed within an iframe, `location.href` should do it. You might want to access the `location` object in more detail tho.

Comment: Oh.. yes that actually did the trick. I thought location.href would give me the url of the location bar. Thanks!